# Compute the area of the region cut from a plane by a cylinder

Tags: surface-integrals

Compute the area of the region cut from the plane $x+y+z = a$ by the cylinder $x^2 +y^2 = a^2$.

The solution I am reading is [here](http://math.mit.edu/~hezari/hw12sol.pdf). I understand how they parametrized $x$ and $y$ in $r(u,v)$, but why is the parameterization of $z$ equal to $a−u \cos v−u \sin v$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use cylindrical coordinates

$$x=u\cos v,\\y=u\sin v$$ because the equation of the cylindre becomes  simply $$u=a.$$

The equation of the plane is a mere substitution

$$u\cos v+u\sin v+z=a.$$